# Не понимаю почему осуществляется пост запрос в форме

Tags: reactjs, html5, postgresql, jsx

Проблема в том, что в одном проекте нормально переносится после регистрации в каталог, а в другом нет. Пишет cannot post /login

Код где не работает

```
const Registration = observer(() => {
const {user} = useContext(Context)
const location = useLocation()
const navigate = useNavigate()
const [fio, setFio] = useState('')
const [passport, setPassport] = useState('')
const [phone, setPhone] = useState('')
const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
const [login, setLogin] = useState('')
const [password, setPassword] = useState('')

const click = async () => {
    try {
        let data;
            data = await registration(fio, passport, phone, email, login, password)
            console.log(data)
        user.setUser(user)
        user.setIsAuth(true)
        navigate(CATALOG__ROUTE)

    } catch (e){
        alert(e.response.data.message)
    }

}


return (
    <div className="container__auth">
        <div className="img">
            <img className="post" src={Logo} alt=""/>
        </div>

        <div className="login-container">
            <form action="/login" method="POST">
```

Код где работает

```
const Auth = observer(() => {


const {user} = useContext(Context)
const location = useLocation()
const navigate = useNavigate()
const isLogin = location.pathname === LOGIN_ROUTE
const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
const [name, setName] = useState('')
const [numberPhone, setNumberPhone] = useState('')
const [password, setPassword] = useState('')

const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.input');


const click = async () => {
    try {
        let data;
        if (isLogin){
            data = await login(email, password)
        } else {
            data = await registration(email, name, password, numberPhone)
            console.log(data)

        }
        user.setUser(user)
        user.setIsAuth(true)
        navigate(SHOP_ROUTE)
    } catch (e){
        alert(e.response.data.message)
    }

}

return (
    <div className="container__auth">
        <div className="img">
            <img className="post" src={Logo} alt=""/>
        </div>

        <div className="login-container">
            <form action="/login" method="POST">
```

Парни помогите, я уже ничего не понимаю

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было просто поменять тип кнопки на button